# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Log_Exception' windows

Tags: windows, zend-framework, wampserver, httpd.conf

I'm newbie on Zend Framework,I'm using WampServer, I want a folder that save logs,

I modified httpd.config to this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName phpweb20

DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\phpweb20\htdocs

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory C:\wamp\www\phpweb20\htdocs>

DirectoryIndex index.php

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

Allow from all

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and I was added host to *C:\windows\sys32\drivers\etc* 
also, I was added path in system variable 
this is my file directory:
[image]

first of all , in my **setting.ini**, in [development] I inserted logging.file:

```
[development]

database.type       = pdo_mysql
database.hostname   = localhost
database.username   = phpweb20
database.password   = myPassword
database.database   = phpweb20

paths.base      = /../phpweb20
paths.data      = /../data
paths.templates = /../phpweb20/templates

logging.file = /../data/logs/debug.log
```

also , I was added this code to my **index.php**:

```
 $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('../data/logs');
 $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
 $logger = new Zend_Log(new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream($config->logging->file));
 Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
```

but error appears :
**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Log_Exception' with message '"../data/logs" cannot be opened with mode "a"'** , how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your path from:

```
logging.file = /../data/logs/debug.log
```

to:

```
logging.file = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/logs/debug.log"
```

Don't forget about suitable permissions for data/logs directory.

Moreover, $writer is unnecessary in your code, because you're overwriting $logger with writer created inline.

Then remove:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('../data/logs');
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
```

from your code.

Comment: thanks for your question, still error appears, for permission, I right click on data and in Sharing Tab->Advanced Sharing->Permission-> Full Control for everyone , I was added Everyone to User in Security tab, is it enough ?

Comment: I don't know how to set permissions on Windows. :) What is the output of: die(var_dump($config->logging->file)) in your index.php?